# Expressions or idioms that mean killing appropriate for use in a humorous context

Tags: expressions, idioms

I'm looking for expressions or idioms that sound funny/unusual and mean killing something. For example, I remember when I was playing Starcraft, there was a mission in which my marines had to kill some creature. At the end of the mission, they said that they `eighty-sixed` that creature. To me, that sounded funny, but I don't know how it sounds for native speakers.

Comment: "86ed" is used to say that you got rid of something.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_expressions_related_to_death

Comment: I actually did, before posting this. I think most of those are not unusual anymore. I don't know if it's appropriate to ask on the site, but I'd appreciate inventions, too.

Comment: Search *Send 'em down to see old hob.*

Comment: @vickyace Is "listing " allowed in this forum? Other SE don't permit it.

Comment: @Gandalf It is allowed in moderation and only as an answer to a question where needs and uses are specified. This question is opinion based and too broad. It will be closed for the said reasons plus because it is not specific.

Comment: @vickyace I think it's quite specific, but I'd rather have a useful answer than have it closed, so feel free to edit it to correspond to SE standards.

Comment: @user3653831 You should realize that you yourself can form expressions that can be easily understood.

Comment: @vickyace that would take care of the "unusual" part as I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: You can use *rip someone's head off* *remove his spine* *take him down* *kill/terminate his ass* *get him a house in hell* *dispatch to the devil*. Get creative.

Comment: @user3653831 So I suggest you find an idiom in your native language and translate it literally to English. It will probably be understood, but will sound weird to natives.

Comment: "Made him take a dirt nap" is popular around here.

Comment: @user3653831 Asking for *inventions* or new word formations aren't allowed here. :)

Comment: Star Trek references: (1) He's a [***redshirt***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshirt_(character)). (2) [***He's dead, Jim.***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_McCoy#.22He.27s_dead.2C_Jim.21.22) I'll add that games and fiction are probably the only conversational topics where I would casually refer to death.

Answer (score 2):

We used to laugh uncontrollably when threatened by our Gym instructor with, "I'll tear off your right-arm and beat you to death with the bloody stump."

Now that I think of it…

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of jokey euphemistic expressions synonymous with dying, and the Monty Python dead parrot sketch provides quite a few. Here are some more: [List of expressions related to death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_expressions_related_to_death).

You asked however specifically about killing. Honestly there aren't many jokey slang terms for this, probably because most people are unlikely to be flippant about taking someone's life. I don't really find "eighty six" especially funny, just a bit weird.

Most of the slang I can think of is the sort of stuff you'd hear in old mob movies, where a hitman is reporting on a murder. Examples: "I did him", "I did him in", "I dusted him", "I iced him", "I offed him", "I smoked him", "I whacked him".

From a newer genre of crime movies (e.g. Pulp Fiction) you'll hear stuff like "I popped a cap in his ass" meaning "I shot him to death".

Slightly more poetic are "I sent him down to Davy Jones" or "[He sleeps with the fishes](http://godfather.wikia.com/wiki/Luca_Brasi#Murder)", both of which refer to killing someone by drowning, or at least disposing of a murder victim in water.

Answer (score 0):

While not precisely to the point, you can't do better than Monty Python [It's resting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vuW6tQ0218).

Comment: **Tis but a scratch!** :)